# Unable to connect to the frida server: need Gadget to attach on jailed Android

Tags: android, frida, sslpinning

I am using objection to bypass ssl pining on injured android apk. After I ran this command successfully `objection patchapk --source injured.apk`
and uninstall and reinstall the patched apk again, I tried objection explore but always get this error.
I tried to download frida gadget-arm and made a folder in the same path in the error message but without any success.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post console output as screenshot, just copy and paste it as text into your question.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue when I was running the APK on an x86 emulator.

What worked for me was

1 Specifying x86 architecture while patching the APK

```
objection patchapk --source UnCrackable-Level1.apk --architecture x86
```

2 Copy the Frida gadget from objection to an expected location

```
cp ~/.objection/android/x86/libfrida-gadget.so ~/.cache/frida/gadget-android-x86.so
```

After doing above 2 steps , then run the APK on the emulator followed by `objection explore`

Answer (score -2):

You need to have the frida-server running on the device. See https://frida.re/docs/android/

Comment: Not if you use the gadget, this is something like an frida-server integrated into the app itself.